# node.js deferred misunderstanding

Tags: node.js, promise, deferred, q

I`m learning q.js and trying to query 3 collections simultaneously with its help (avoiding callback hell):

```
var Q = require('q')
var deferred = Q.defer();
```

**users()** is a wrapper of db.collection.find()

```
var users = function (){
    Auth.listUsers({role:'user'}, call)
    return deferred.promise
}
```

**call()** is a shorthand for exporting promises

```
var call = function (err,data){
    if (err) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    } else {
        deferred.resolve(data);
    }
}
```

**loop()** is main loop, which gets cursor and loops through entries

```
var loop = function (result) {
    var list = []
    var promises = [];
    result.each(function (err,data){
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else {
            deferred.resolve(data);
            promises.push(deferred.promise)
            console.log('promises_:', promises) // <- internal
        }
    })
    console.log('promises:', promises) // <- external
    return Q.all(promises)
}
```

code:

```
users()
  .then(loop)
  .then(function(ful){
            console.log('ful:', ful);  // <- here should come the queries to other collections
        })
```

result of console logging at the end:

```
promises: []    //external is empty
ful: []
promises_: [ [object Object] ]  // internal is being filled
promises_: [ [object Object], [object Object] ]
```

As you can see, the callback of `.each` is executed later than pushing promises to array.
I believe it can be made by using `result.toArray()` instead of `.each`, but how can it be done with the help of `.each` loop?

result is a cursor, returned by mongodb driver after db.collection.find() call (http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find).

Comment: Where are you getting `each()` from? Have you tried it with the Javascript function `forEach()`? It might work better for you. Also, I'm not sure that I follow the `result.each()` call having the `function (err,data)` does your `each` call with an error?

Comment: Where are you getting each of those `deferred` variables from?

Comment: added the asked information.

Comment: Got it, thanks - I am not a mongo person, but if I am following this correctly, I think your general problem is that the `.each()` method is getting executed asynchronously, but isn't part of your promise scheme. You might want to use `Q.ninvoke`, `Q.denodeify`, or some similar strategy so that the `each()` is returning a promise. Also, and I know you are clearly stripping out some code, but as written, you just have one `deferred` you are operating on. Inside your loop, you are just populating the array with multiple copies of the same promise, which in the line prior line you are resolving.

Comment: You are right, `.each()` is async. Couldn't understand the `Q` functions (`.fcall`, `.ncall`, etc.). Can you recommend a good tutorial or a detailed manual on this library? I was not satisfied with its homepage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var deferred = Q.defer();
> …
> deferred.resolve(…);
> …
> deferred.resolve(…);
> ```
>
> `call()` is a shorthand for exporting promises

That will not work! You need to create a new deferred for each promise that you want. However, you [shouldn't use `Deferred`s anyway](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#wiki-the-deferred-anti-pattern)! Instead, use the [many](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-promise-for-function-methods) [Node callback helper functions](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#adapting-node).

---

> As you can see, the callback of .each is executed later than pushing promises to array. I believe it can be made by using result.toArray() instead of .each, but how can it be done with the help of .each loop?

It cannot, unless you know beforehand how often `each` will be called and how many promises will need to be created. `Q.all` is a bit useless in here, since the promises are not created at once and execute their tasks in parallel - instead, they are a stream.

You really should use `toArray` here, to get a single callback with which you resolve the promise.

Well, there is a way, but it's ugly and less efficient than `toArray`. You can have one deferred that will always wait, and is only resolved with a promise for the rest of the stream.

```
function loop(result) {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    result.each(function (err,data){
        if (err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        } else if (data == null) {
            deferred.resolve([]); // end of the stream
        } else {
            var nextDeferred = Q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(nextDeferred.promise.then(function(rest) {
                return [data].concat(rest);
            }));
            deferred = nextDeferred;
        }
    })
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your attention. I will try  `.toArray()`. Can it be, that `someArray.forEach(callbackFunction())` is executed syncronously? In mongodb driver `.each()` is documented to be async.

Comment: Yes, [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) != `each`.